# gradle return fail after build success

Tags: jenkins, gradle, automation

I have a Jenkins script that run automation tests on android device, after all tests run on the device i got issue on gradle

```
Received result Success[value=null] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=9464, address=[fb8f1f37-27ab-4a23-b86a-197e77780d1c port:63054, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1493544371434, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=47529e23-e8b7-42cb-9131-ba2d54045035,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\someuser\.gradle\daemon,pid=9464,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1255,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILUR
```

more over when I run the test from the computer itself the test pass successfully

Edit:
the part of gradle log that I have issue with

```
15:33:09.270 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle\.gradle\3.1\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin)
15:33:09.270 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle\.gradle\3.1\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin)
15:33:09.271 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle\.gradle\3.1\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin)
15:33:09.271 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle\.gradle\3.1\taskArtifacts).
15:33:09.273 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-versions.bin (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.21\module-versions.bin)
15:33:09.273 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.21\module-metadata.bin)
15:33:09.273 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.21\artifact-at-repository.bin)
15:33:09.273 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
15:33:09.274 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
15:33:09.275 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
15:33:09.275 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
15:33:09.276 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\3.1\plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
15:33:09.276 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
15:33:09.276 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
15:33:09.276 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory workerMain (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\3.1\workerMain).
15:33:09.277 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache jars (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\jars-1) was closed 0 times.
15:33:09.277 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\3.1\generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
15:33:09.277 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
15:33:09.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
15:33:09.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: finished waiting for DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=aa7ffae6-dcc7-4e0d-bfcb-a062735331d0.1, currentDir=c:\jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle}, connection = org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection@ee70914]. Result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator@522eb22b with state Busy
15:33:09.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: completed DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=aa7ffae6-dcc7-4e0d-bfcb-a062735331d0.1, currentDir=c:\jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle}, connection = org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection@ee70914]
15:33:09.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1493555589488
15:33:09.488 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the daemon as idle, address: [2c920926-ad81-4560-8c7e-391126091221 port:51336, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
15:33:09.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking busy by address: [2c920926-ad81-4560-8c7e-391126091221 port:51336, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
15:33:09.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:33:09.491 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
15:33:09.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:33:09.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
15:33:09.494 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult] Daemon is dispatching the build result: Success[value=null]
15:33:09.494 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 15: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Success
15:33:09.496 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Finishing executing command: Build{id=aa7ffae6-dcc7-4e0d-bfcb-a062735331d0.1, currentDir=c:\jenkins\workspace\xxxx-02-AutomationGradle}
15:33:09.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 16: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
15:33:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 16: Received non-IO message from client: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished@644ca32d
15:33:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Received finished message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished@644ca32d
15:33:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 15: stopping connection
15:33:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection] Discarding EOFException: java.io.EOFException
15:33:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 16: received null
15:33:09.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 16: Received end-of-input from client.
15:33:09.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 15: stopping connection
15:33:14.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
15:33:14.021 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:33:14.022 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
15:33:14.023 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:33:14.026 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:33:14.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
```

Comment: Can you add the Gradle console output? Your output does not show what Gradle actually did.

Comment: how do I get to this console?

Comment: Whenever I use Jenkins, I see the full Gradle console output in the Jenkins build result console output. I never setup a Jenkins server, so maybe it must be enabled.

Comment: it may be a problem of memory ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I'll i solved my own issue , and mybe will help others.
from some reason from the code we close all cmd and the gradle see this as an issue so we change to close the cmd with another job after this job